# Concrete5: Is it possible to access the value set by set() function from another function in the controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, concrete5

In my controller's view() function, I have something like this:

```
function view() {    
  $this->set('myVal', $text);
}
```

Now is it possible to access `$myVal` from another custom function inside the controller?

I tried `$myVal` and `$this->myVal` but it does not work. Is it only accessible in the add.php, edit.php and view.php and not anywhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it via

```
$this->getvar('myVal');
```

You can also access it via

```
$this->get('myVal');
```

But this is deprecated as that method should now be used for `$_GET` values